# Can I consume a consumable In-App purchase as a user?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, in-app-purchase

As a developer I let my app's users buy in-app purchases (IAPs) and then the app lets Google know that the IAP is consumed so it can be purchased again.

Is that possible for me as an app ***user***? That is, if the app is stuck somehow not consuming the IAP and I want to force it to do so, is there somewhere on my Google account where I can see all of the outstanding IAPs and consume them?